# Navigate to ViewController from UIAlertController button click

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, uialertcontroller

I am quite new to Swift development and I tried referring to the Swift UIAlertController API but couldn't figure out how to navigate to another UIViewController after clicking a button on the UIAlertController.

I would appreciate any pointers, help or a solution to this problem. My code snippet is given below -

```
@IBAction func showAlert() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message: "Disclaimer Text Here", preferredStyle: .Alert)


    let declineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(declineAction)

    let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in

        let secondVC = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    alertController.addAction(acceptAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

What I am trying to do here is when a button is clicked the disclaimer AlertController is displayed. If *"Decline"* button is selected, cancel action is performed and if *"Accept"* is selected the app should navigate to a Navigation Controller which then allows me to navigate to other ViewControllers using a menu in the application.

Earlier I used the story board to link a button to the NavigationController to traverse to the ViewController I desired. Now I want to do the same programmatically for the AlertController *"Accept"* Button.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically to link the UIAlertViewController button to a UINavigationController's UIViewController we would need to create a manual segue between the UIViewController which has the UIAlertViewController to the UINavigationController.

Please refer to this screen shot to see how to do the above -

[image]

Then select the link between the UIViewController and the UINavigationController. Go to the left sidebar and select the Attributes inspector and name the identifier.

Now write the following in your code -

```
@IBAction func showAlert() {

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message: "Before using this teaching resource, you confirm that you agree:\n1. To obey the law regarding data protection and patient confidentiality.\n2. To us this app professionally and appropriately in clinical settings.\n3. This is for your personal use and you may not modify, distribute, publish, transfer any information obtained from this teaching resource without the developers' permission.\n4. In no event shall the developer be liable to you for any loss arising from your use of this resource.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let declineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in    

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeSegue", sender: self) // Replace SomeSegue with your segue identifier (name)
}

alertController.addAction(declineAction)
alertController.addAction(acceptAction)

presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the handler block to perform code when an action is selected :

```
@IBActionfunc showAlert() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message: "Disclaimer Text Here", preferredStyle: .Alert)


    let declineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(declineAction)

    let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in

        let secondVC = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondView", bundle: nil)
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(acceptAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Thats awesome of you! Thanks! :) Now how do I navigate to a NavigationController using the same button instead of just one viewcontroller? The other viewcontrollers are linked to the NavigationController.

Comment: I have edited my answer if i understood you correctly ;)

Comment: I think you have understood what I mean! I edited my code from your help, it stops execution and says "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". Any idea where may I have gone wrong?

Comment: You should be more explicit about the error : do you have any breakpoint where it crash or more informations ?  You should edit your question with the newly added code.

Comment: I have edited my question and code. I appreciate all the help Michaël :)

Comment: According to your edited question, you try to instantiate a UIViewController with the view embedded in a storyboard. The initialisation process is not the same, the example i give was based on a separate .xib file, try `let secondVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController ` instead.

Comment: I did make it work though I did it by creating a manual segue and then invoking it in the accept button. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it. I will post the answer to my question below.

Answer (score 1):

That's the use of the handler block. You should make your desired action in this block.

Edit: Code

```
let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .Default, handler:{  action in 
    //Write your code here
})
```

You can use this link as a reference: http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/

Comment: Could you please post a sample snippet of code just as an example? Much appreciated

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Now I can do this, I was wondering if I can navigate to a NavigationController viewcontroller so that it allows me to navigate further in the app using a menu.

Comment: I don't get the part of using a menu.

Comment: I have a StartViewController with the alertcontroller. Now when I click accept, I want to navigate to a navigationcontroller stack (which will help me traverse using a slide menu bar to other parts of my app). So I want to know how can I navigate to the navigationcontroller stack which has ViewController1.

Comment: You can push a navigation controller inside a navigation controller. Or you can set the mainWindow.rootViewController to the navigation controller you want.

Comment: I am quite new and I am a bit confused now. Sorry. I will try explaining again. Earlier I used the story board to link a button to the NavigationController to traverse to the screen I desired. Now I want to do the same programmatically for the AlertController Button. Does that make sense?

Comment: Aha, something like the push segue you made in storyboard?