# UIAlertController: push view controller upon UIAlertAction (hitting "Ok" button)

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, uialertcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to open a new view controller by calling `pushViewController` when the user hit a specific button of a UIAlertController popup message.

I tried the following (code is in the rootViewController):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "My message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {action in
     let vc = ViewController2()
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
     print("called pushViewController")
}))
```

The message "called pushViewController" gets successfully printed. However, I the new viewController does not appear (the same commands work for displaying the second view controller when not executed outside of this setting).

My theory would be, that when this action gets called, the `UIAlertController` is on top of the initial view controller and this prohibits to call the command `pushViewController` from the initial view controller - is this right?

How can I solve this?

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437489/4673476) did not work even after updating to the code to the new Swift. Even though, there should be a solution with the commands above, as they work in every other case to push a view controller.

Comment: Change `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` to `self.present`

Answer (score 0):

If your code executes without crashes, I guess that your navigationController is nil. To check this, set a breakpoint at

```
print("called pushViewController")
```

and check if

```
self.navigationController
```

is nil or not. If it is nil, then you don't have a navigation controller and therefore cannot push a new vc on the stack. The following line will still be executed, which seems to happen in your case.

Comment: It is nil. Does this support my theory and how can I solve it?

Comment: No. It just means that the view controller that presents the alert is not embedded in a navigation controller. Therefore you cannot push another view controller onto the stack of the navigation controller. If you use interface builder, select the view controller and select "Editor" -> "Embed In" -> "Navigation Controller".

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this on tapping `ok`

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let dVC: ViewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your vc2 stroryboard identifier") as! ViewController2
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dVC, animated: true)
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

As you explained, first I would recommend you to use alert style **.actionsheet** instead of **.alert**.

As you commented in one of the answer as **navigationController** is nil then you need to add navigation controller to that particular view controller from where you want to redirect. Do as follow :

Select view controller -> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller